# Axios not using proxy setting with https

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, outlook-addin, redux-thunk

I am trying to make a request from a react (with redux) front-end outlook add-id which runs over HTTPS using axios. I want to use the proxy setting in  package.json so I only have to use /path/to/endpoint in my requests however, the backend runs over http and while both are on the local host, it seems axios does not use the proxy setting and will not redirct to a non https endpoint. I have tried running the backend over https, sending the request to the secure heroku server where I actually host the backend which DOES run https, adding the axios-proxy-fix package but nothing seems to work. So my current setup is as follows (with irrelevant code removed): 
package.json file:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {...}, 
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

my authActions.js file where I make the request:

```
export const signupUser = (userData) => dispatch {
  axios.post('/auth/user/signup', userData)
       .then(...)
       .catch(...);
};
```

Then I get this error: 
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (HTTP/2.0 400)     https://localhost:3000/auth/user/signup".

I would have expected the path to be http://localhost:5000/auth/user/signup since that is where the proxy specifies and that is where my backend is running. However, It is trying to access port 3000... which is the port the front end is running on over https.

Does anyone have any suggestions? My only other idea is to try without axios as maybe fetch can use the proxy setting?

Answer (score 0):

> The development server will only attempt to send requests without
>   text/html in its Accept header to the proxy.

... from [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development).

Are you including that header by any chance?

Comment: No, I only specify "Content-Type": "application/json", and Accept: "application/json".

Comment: I did find the part about configuring the proxy yourself from the link you provided useful though so thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

So after some searching I found a three step solution.

First I had to run the dev server over https by using the command HTTPS=true npm run server (server is my script name).

Second I had to specify that I wanted a secure proxy in my package.json file as follows:

```
"proxy": {
"secure": true,
"target": {
  "host": "https://localhost",
  "port": 5000
  }
}
```

Finally, I changed my ajax request to use fetch rather than axios.

I hope this helps someone if they find themselves in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this issue. One other possible solution is:

check to make sure you are using the package.json from your React app fold and not from your server folder.

Second possible issue you just need to run npm build on your react project.